# Apple API usage rejects from App Store Submission

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, react-native

I'm using v7.2 of the Mobile SDK included with the forcereact npm project.  When submitting the app to Salesforce I'm getting 3 failures.  Something is using NSPhotoLibrary, NSLocationAlways, and NSLocationWhenInUse.  Apple requires a user-facing purpose string for these in the submission.  Are these messages valid?  I couldn't find a reference in the SDK github project.  If so, what are they being used for?

Answer (score 0):

**As per Apple Guide Rules**, If your app uses *Location*, *Photo* Library or Any other *Private services*, You need to specify `usage description string` in your **info.plist** file. 
It might also possible that you are not using these functionalities directly from your side but some SDK uses it. 
**Here is what you need to add in your info.plist file.**

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key> //NSPhotoLibrary
<string>This app requires access to the photo library.</string>
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key> //NSLocationWhenInUse
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key> //NSLocationAlways
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

[You can have more detailed Key description from this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39519960/5350718).

**Note:** Please specify valid description of why your app needs to use key you are specifying otherwise Apple can again reject your app.